# Obscure curses error message when creating a sub window

Tags: python, ncurses, curses

I have a simple python curses code that creates a subwindow. However, in the process of running the function window.subwin() fails with the message:

Here a test case:

```
import curses

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.initscr()

    window = curses.newwin(15, 40, 7, 20)
    window.box()
    window.refresh()

    subwindow = window.subwin(5, 10, 2, 2)
    subwindow.box()
    subwindow.refresh()

    subwindow.getkey()

    curses.endwin()
```

produces the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c.py", line 12, in <module>
  subwindow = window.subwin(5, 10, 2, 2)
_curses.error: curses function returned NULL
```

Is there any way to get a more descriptive message?

Comment: Please, add a test case, a short self-contained example that reproduce the error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error likely happens when it is not possible to create a sub-window (illegal operation).  This can happen because you are asking to paint the sub-window outside of the window.

The method *subwin* receives absolute coordinates (with respect to the screen, not the parent window).  It will fail if the *subwin* coordinates are outside of *window*.  Another reason to fail: the width or height overflows the window.

Instead of *subwin*, you can use *derwin* (derivated window), which receives relatives coordinates (less prone to error).

```
import curses

if __name__ == '__main__':
    curses.initscr()

    window = curses.newwin(15, 40, 7, 20)
    window.box()
    window.refresh()

    subwindow = window.derwin(5, 10, 2, 2)  # <- here is the change
    subwindow.box()
    subwindow.refresh()

    subwindow.getkey()

    curses.endwin()
```